# Is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i) + c = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k) + c + \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2j+1) + c$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integers

Basically, the question is, "is the sum of all positive numbers equal to the sum of all positive even numbers and odd numbers?" (which is obviously yes) but with a twist: for every number, there is a constant $c$ which is also an integer.

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i) + c = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k) + c + \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2j+1) + c$$

It really feels like this equation is true, as there should be an equal amount of $c$'s in both sides but I am not a mathematician at all, just equipped with high school maths, I wanted a proper explanation for this from you guys! Couldn't find this question when googling, sorry in advance if there is one.

Comment: Yes, because $$+\infty=(+\infty)+(+\infty)$$

Comment: @Did excuse my ignorance, but what about $c$? In the first term we have one $c$ and in the second two. Strictly speaking shouldn't we have two $c/2$ in the second term?

Comment: @cgiovanardi You may replace each occurrence of $c$ by whichever constant you want, say $a$ in the first series, $b$ in the second series and $c$ in the third series, and the identity still holds. As food for thought, note that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-42)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sum: $$1+2+3+… $$ diverges, so they sum to $\infty$ on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i) + c = \infty = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k) + c + \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2j+1) + c.$$